# Django Tastypie: post value in multiple models to a single Tastypie Resource

Tags: django, tastypie

First model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(
                r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                _('Enter a valid username. This value may contain only '
                  'letters, numbers ' 'and @/./+/-/_ characters.')
            ),
        ],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
   password = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='123456')
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
```

second model:

```
class UserEbiz(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Profile')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='123456')
```

Tastypie Resource:

```
class ProfileResources(ModelResource):
    id = fields.CharField(attribute='id')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Profile.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'profile'

        filtering = {
            "id": ALL,
        }
```

I want to create a function that can save a value to both table at the same time by using only one resource. My question is how to post value into Profile and UserEbiz models using ProfileResources.

Comment: Why are you not creating a resource for UserEbiz model...!

Comment: Ok. After I create resource for UserEbiz model, what should I do for the next step.

Answer (score 2):

@sean-hayes Answer is fine But if You really want to `Post` data on `ProfileResource` instead of `UserEbiz` first change `ProfileResource` to

```
class ProfileResource(ModelResource):
    ebiz = fields.ToManyField(UserEbizResource, 'userebiz_set', readonly=True)
```

Notice **First** that you have a `ForeignKey` of `Profile`. So it is `1:M` for `Profile` to `UserEbiz`.

**Second** i have set `readonly` to true because i am going to handle `UserEbiz` data myself. However if You have   `models.ForeignKey('Profile', blank=True, null=True)` then it is just like creating `M2M` data so just remove the `readonly` attribute and you are all set.

So you can `override` the `obj_create` to handle `ebiz` data yourself. Code might look like

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    ebiz = bundle.data.pop('ebiz', None)
    bundle = super(ProfileResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
    if not ebiz:
        return bundle

    ebiz.update(user_id=bundle.obj) # change it to user in model and here
    ebiz_res = UserEbizResource()
    ebiz_bundle = ebiz_res.build_bundle(data=ebiz)
    ebiz_res.obj_create(ebiz_bundle)
    return bundle
```

Comment: I have already tried your code but i get this error "error_message": "super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type",

Comment: @nuriffah you are not passing resource instance to super class. Can you update your question with How you are using ```obj_create```...!

Comment: I have already solve that error but when post already success in Profileresource but not in UserEbizResource..data not save into UserEbiz models.

Comment: @nuriffah that is Impossible.. :) are you sending any data in ebiz at all...like { "ebiz" : { "password" : "something"} }

Comment: no. I just send data into ProfileResource. What should i do to submit into Profile and after that submit into ebiz.

Comment: I have already add "ebiz" : { "password" : "somepassword"} and i got this error 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
class UserEbizResource(ModelResource):
    user_id = fields.ToOneField(ProfileResources, attribute='user_id')

    class Meta:
        queryset = UserEbiz.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'userebiz'

        excludes = ['password']
        filtering = {
            "id": ALL,
        }
```

Some other suggestions:

- Rename `ProfileResources` to `ProfileResource`
- Rename `UserEbiz.user_id` to `UserEbiz.profile`
- Consider using Django's User model or customizing it instead of a completely custom model